# How to resolve the timeout error while creating Ksql stream?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

when I tried to create a stream, I keep getting this message. pls help

Could not write the statement 'create stream userprofile(userid int, firstname varchar) with(VALUE_FORMAT='json', KAFKA_TOPIC='userprofile');' into the command topic.

Caused by: Timeout while waiting for command topic consumer to process command

topic

Comment: You should provide the ksql server logs

Comment: Is the Kafka cluster up and running and accessible?

Comment: Yes it's running